# Recursively rename files (change extension) in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, file-management, rename

How do I rename all files in a directory, recursively, changing one file extension to another, for thousands of files in thousands of subfolders?  I see a lot of commands that do almost what I want, but not quite.

```
find . -name "*.andnav" -exec rename .andnav .tile {} \;
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "."
```

...

```
rename -nv 's/\.andnav$/\.tile/i' *.andnav
0.png.andnav renamed as 0.png.tile
```

Comment: Do you have Debian `rename` or Red Hat `rename`?

Comment: @Ignacio: Ubuntu = Debian?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu is a Debian derivative.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Figured it out

```
find . -name "*.andnav" -exec rename -v 's/\.andnav$/\.tile/i' {} \;
./0/0.png.andnav renamed as ./0/0.png.tile
./0/1.png.andnav renamed as ./0/1.png.tile
./1/0.png.andnav renamed as ./1/0.png.tile
./1/1.png.andnav renamed as ./1/1.png.tile
```

of course remove the -v when actually doing it, or it will waste time displaying all the files

Answer (score 28):

With zsh:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(**/)(*).andnav' '$1$2.tile'
```

Remove the `-n` to actually perform the renaming.

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Answer (score 27):

Something like:

```
find . -name '*.andnav' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.andnav}.tile"' {} \;
```

#### Explanation

The above starts walking the directory tree starting at the current working directory (`.`). Every time a file name matches the pattern `*.andnav` (e.g., `foo.andnav`) the following command is executed:

```
sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.andnav}.tile"' foo.andnav
```

Where `$0` is `foo.andnav` and `${0%.andnav}.tile` replaces the `.andnav` suffix with `.tile` so basically:

```
mv foo.andnav foo.tile
```

Comment: this one worked best for me

Comment: what is this doing?

Comment: @user1028270 supposedly what the OP asked.

Comment: I just meant an explanation of the syntax and behaviour- people (like me!) might not be familiar with bash parameter expansion

Comment: @user1028270 Got it!, See the update.

Comment: Would this work when used to find and rename recursively?

Comment: What does the {} \ mean at the end?

Comment: @JosephAstrahan `{}` is the placeholder and `;` denotes the end of the command `\` is used to quote `;` because that's a special shell character (`';'` would do as well). See `man find` and lookup `-exec`.

Answer (score 4):

I found this method is easier and easier to read:

```
find . -name "*.andnav" | rename "s/\.andnav$/.tile/"
```

At least on Ubuntu derivations rename takes a list of files from STDIN if none are on the command line. And this can be tested easily with:

```
find . -name "*.andnav" | rename -vn "s/\.andnav$/.tile/"
```

until you get it right.

Answer (score 1):

**`find -execdir rename`**

https://superuser.com/a/213146/128124 works directly only for suffixes, but this will work for arbitrary regex replacements on basenames:

```
PATH=/usr/bin find . -depth -execdir rename 's/_dbg.txt$/_.txt' '{}' \;
```

or to affect files only:

```
PATH=/usr/bin find . -type f -execdir rename 's/_dbg.txt$/_.txt' '{}' \;
```

`-execdir` first `cd`s into the directory before executing only on the basename.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, find 4.7.0, rename 1.10.

**Convenient and safer helper for it**

```
find-rename-regex() (
  set -eu
  find_and_replace="$1"
  PATH="$(echo "$PATH" | sed -E 's/(^|:)[^\/][^:]*//g')" \
    find . -depth -execdir rename "${2:--n}" "s/${find_and_replace}" '{}' \;
)
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/dotfiles/blob/8537885b7ad122ae12892177674c31c88461e3ba/home/.bashrc#L2195).

Sample usage to replace spaces ' ' with hyphens '-'.

Dry run that shows what would be renamed to what without actually doing it:

```
find-rename-regex ' /-/g'
```

Do the replace:

```
find-rename-regex ' /-/g' -v
```

**Command explanation**

The awesome `-execdir` option does a `cd` into the directory before executing the `rename` command, unlike `-exec`.

`-depth` ensure that the renaming happens first on children, and then on parents, to prevent potential problems with missing parent directories.

`-execdir` is required because rename does not play well with non-basename input paths, e.g. the following fails:

```
rename 's/findme/replaceme/g' acc/acc
```

The `PATH` hacking is required because `-execdir` has one very annoying drawback: `find` is extremely opinionated and refuses to do anything with `-execdir` if you have any relative paths in your `PATH` environment variable, e.g. `./node_modules/.bin`, failing with:

> find: The relative path ‘./node_modules/.bin’ is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove that entry from $PATH

See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/621132/why-using-the-execdir-action-is-insecure-for-directory-which-is-in-the-path/1109378#1109378

`-execdir` is a GNU find [extension to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html). `rename` is Perl based and comes from the `rename` package.

**Rename lookahead workaround**

If your input paths don't come from `find`, or if you've had enough of the relative path annoyance, we can use some Perl lookahead to safely rename directories as in:

```
git ls-files | sort -r | xargs rename 's/findme(?!.*\/)\/?$/replaceme/g' '{}'
```

I haven't found a convenient analogue for `-execdir` with `xargs`: [Xargs: change working directory to file path before executing?](https://superuser.com/questions/893890/xargs-change-working-directory-to-file-path-before-executing/915686)

The `sort -r` is required to ensure that files come after their respective directories, since longer paths come after shorter ones with the same prefix.

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 0):

If you have zsh shell, this is satisfaction:

```bsh
rename -n -e 'EXPRESSION_HERE' **/*
```

Remove `-n` to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have started to put together a [tool](https://github.com/mountbuild/mouse) to provide a simplified interface to common actions.

You can recursively rename files with glob pattern matching and regex matching like this:

```
$ npm install @mountbuild/mouse -g
$ mouse rename file -p "tmp/**/*.jpg" -i "\.jpg" -o ".png"
```

If nothing else check out the source and see how to write your own script to do this in JavaScript.