# How can I recursively rename all files in a folder?

Tags: linux, command-line, batch-rename

I'm using linux and I have a project with files named `myproject-someextention.whatever` and `someotherstuffmyproject` and so on.

I'd like to recursively rename everything that has `myproject` in the file / folder name and rename it to `yourproject`.

Comment: Please have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/213134/recursively-rename-files-change-extension-in-linux

Comment: Never done before in the history of mankind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rename` from util-linux (http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux).

```
$ find .
.
./yourprojectfolder
./yourprojectfolder/source.of.yourproject
./yourproject.manifest

$ find . -type d -exec rename yourproject myproject {} \;
find: `./yourprojectfolder': No such file or directory

$ find . -type f -exec rename yourproject myproject {} \;

$ find .
.
./myprojectfolder
./myprojectfolder/source.of.myproject
./myproject.manifest
```